# How do I mute different sounds in actionscript3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, action

i want to have the music always playing and the ability to mute different parts. It is for a project where you click on different people and they come to life to play music. a stop and play would not have them in snyc. I have not been using action script long

```
var my_sound:Sound = new Sound();
my_sound.load(new URLRequest("triumphant.mp3" ) );
function setMute(vol){
var sTransform:SoundTransform = new SoundTransform(0);
sTransform.volume = vol; 
SoundMixer.soundTransform = sTransform;
}
my_sound.play();
setMute(0)
//2.
//3.
var Mute:Boolean = true;
play_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, toggleMuteBtn)
function toggleMuteBtn(event:Event) { 
if (Mute) { 
    Mute = false; 
    setMute(1);
     }
    else{ Mute = true; setMute(0 );

     }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should assign each sound to a different channel. Each channel has it's own volume and pan transformation.

SoundMixer.soundTranform is for the global sound.

```
var _bassSound:Sound = new Sound();
_bassSound.load(new URLRequest("you_mp3.mp3"));

var _bassChannel:SoundChannel = _bassSound.play();
_bassChannel.soundTranform = new SoundTranform(1,0);
```

then you could make your mute function like this

```
function setVolume (soundChannel:SoundChannel, volume:Number=0) {

   var transform:SoundTransform = soundChannel.soundTransform;
   transform.volume = volume;
   soundChannel.soundTransform = transform;

}

// so you call it like this

setVolume(_bassChannel);

// or if you want to unmute

setVolume(_bassChannel, 1);
```

Comment: I'd recommend changing the name of the method from toggleMute to setVolume. Toggle means to switch between two states (often on and off). This method sets the volume to whatever value is specified in the volume parameter (which is set to 0 by default).